# How to make WindowBuilder create fields that are not nested in Eclipse, Java

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, windowbuilder

I am using WindowBuilder for Eclipse Java.

When I make a Button or a Menu (or anything), it creates the fields nested inside of the constructor. Is there any way to make them fields and then initialized in the constructor so I can use them outside of the constructor? Thank you.

ie: FROM

```
public GUIFrame() {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
}
```

TO

```
public JMenuBar menubar; 
public GUIFrame() {
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a button to convert an element from "local to field".

[image: Convert]

If you want all components to be fields by default: Windows -> Preferences -> WindowBuilder -> Swing -> Code Generation -> Find "Variable generation" and select the "Field" tab.

Comment: thanks! I was looking for a way to do this by default, but this is pretty quick and useful