# Eclipse WindowBuilder (swing) - some components not accessible in code?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

Edit - [@Heuster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2095090/heuster) linked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803107/how-to-make-windowbuilder-create-fields-that-are-not-nested-in-eclipse-java) that answers this.

I just found out about WindowBuilder and I'm making a simple chat client using it to teach myself. Right now I've got the basic chat frame done, but only some of the components that I've added are accessible in the code. Specifically, I can't access my input JTextArea, taInput. Is there something I need to do to be able to reference it (to get the text in it for sending, etc.)?

Here's a picture of the Design view:

[image]

And here's a the generated code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class frame extends JFrame
{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JButton btnSend;
    private JTextArea taDisplay;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    frame frame = new frame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public frame()
    {
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle("Client");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 440, 316);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(mnFile);

        JMenuItem mntmConnect = new JMenuItem("Connect...");
        mnFile.add(mntmConnect);

        JMenuItem mntmSaveChatLog = new JMenuItem("Save chat log...");
        mnFile.add(mntmSaveChatLog);

        JMenuItem mntmSettings = new JMenuItem("Settings...");
        mnFile.add(mntmSettings);

        JMenuItem mntmClose = new JMenuItem("Close");
        mnFile.add(mntmClose);

        JMenu mnEdit = new JMenu("Edit");
        menuBar.add(mnEdit);

        JMenu mnView = new JMenu("View");
        menuBar.add(mnView);

        JMenu mnHelp = new JMenu("Help");
        menuBar.add(mnHelp);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        btnSend = new JButton("Send");
        btnSend.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
            {
                taDisplay.append("Send clicked.\n");
            }
        });
        btnSend.setBounds(314, 197, 100, 50);
        panel.add(btnSend);

        taDisplay = new JTextArea();
        taDisplay.setLineWrap(true);
        taDisplay.setEditable(false);
        taDisplay.setBounds(10, 11, 404, 180);
        panel.add(taDisplay);

        JScrollPane spInput = new JScrollPane();
        spInput.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        spInput.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        spInput.setBounds(10, 197, 294, 49);
        panel.add(spInput);

        JTextArea taInput = new JTextArea();
        taInput.setLineWrap(true);
        spInput.setViewportView(taInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11803107/how-to-make-windowbuilder-create-fields-that-are-not-nested-in-eclipse-java

Comment: @Heuster That's it, thanks. I didn't find that when I searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the design tab you could right click on the item (taInput) then click rename on the context menu, in the diaog, at the right of the name there where 2 buttons, clic on the (f) button (field) and then ok.

[image]